# Generate new array with .pop() value

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I am drawing points on a canvas with javascript, like so:

```
function addPointToMap(point) {
    var pointRadius = (document.getElementById(point.canvasId).height * (2 / 66)) / 2;
    var context = document.getElementById(point.canvasId).getContext("2d");
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(point.x, point.y, pointRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fill();
}
```

and all the `point`s I am drawing are stored in an array, `pointMap`. I want the user to only be able to draw one point if a checkbox is ticked, and draw many points if it is not ticked. A new point should override an old one. In order to do this, I have decided to add the new point to the array, and then remove the old one and refresh the canvas. The problem is that `pointMap = pointMap.pop();` is returning an empty array. How do I get the most recent entry in an array and delete all the other entries? Here is what I have so far:

```
if (questionId == 41) {
    if (pointMap.length == 1) {
        //do nothing, user only has 1 point
    } else {
            console.log("PointMap: " + pointMap); //ex. returns [Point, Point] (Point is a custom class I wrote to store the point x and y values)
            pointMap = pointMap.pop(); //this line does not work
            console.log("PointMap: " + pointMap); //ex. returns []
            refreshCanvas();
        }
    }
```

Where am I going wrong? can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Where is `pointMap` declared and populated?

Comment: The fact that you are re-assigning the variable for your list to an element of that list is red flag to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop` returns the popped value, so `pointMap = pointMap.pop()` will replace your array reference with a point.

If you want to only have a single point in the array when the checkbox is checked, simply overwrite it:

```
if (checkboxIsChecked) {
    // Only want one point, assign to index 0 (works whether the
    // array already has a point or not)
    pointMap[0] = theNewPoint;
} else {
    // Want to allow multiple points, push the point onto the array
    pointMap.push(theNewPoint);
}
```

If the user can check the checkbox while there are *already* values in `pointMap`, you'll want to remove all but the last one when they check it. In your event handler for the checkbox:

```
if (checkboxIsChecked && pointMap.length > 1) {
    // Remove all entries except the last pushed one
    pointMap.splice(0, pointMap.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: YES the second solution was perfect. Thank you so much (I will accept the answer when I can in three minutes)